# ADF Lookup query create schema and select

Tags: azure-data-factory, lookup

I am trying to run a create Shema/table query in the ADF lookup activity, with a dummy select in the end.

CREATE SCHEMA [schemax] AUTHORIZATION [auth1];
SELECT 0 AS dummyValue

but I got the below error

A database operation failed with the following error: 'Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=103010,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1

[Data factory pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25dia.png)

I was able to run a similar query without SELECT query in the end but got another error mandating lookup must return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write select statements in `lookup` activity query settings.

To create schema or table, use `copy data` activity pre-copy script in sink settings. You can select a dummy table for the source and sink dataset and write your create script in pre-copy activity as below.

**Source settings:** (using dummy table which pulls 0 records)

[image]

**Sink settings:**

Pre-copy script:  `CREATE SCHEMA test1 AUTHORIZATION [user]`

[image]